# Composer package self hosted

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

How can I create a composer setup that pulls in the required folder and files from a repo hosted on bitbucket?

I use bitbucket for the project, but want to be able to create a separate repo for a specific section of code. If I have an existing folder in my project like vendor/acne how do I turn that into a self hosted private repo that I can pull in via composer?

(e.g so when I run composer update it pulls from my hosted repo as opposed to the 3rd party)

Again I use bitbucket, but not sure how I would do this, I assume some sort of VCS setup, it needs to be private.

Any help would be appreciated GIT is still a learning process.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to manage a private repo in your current repo. Steps as below:

1. Create the private repo.
2. In your current repo, add the private repo as a submodule:

`git remote add <URL for the private repo> foldername`.

3. Pull changes from private repo:

`cd foldername
 git pull`

4. Go to your current repo by `cd ..`.
5. Push changes of private repo:

`cd foldername
 git push`